# Search Table for Multiple Results and Unique ID SQL

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a table with multiple rows of results, and I'm wanting to be able to search it for multiple values, but one unique ID

I'm not sure how to explain it, but say I have a user with multiple items assigned to them. So for example, I want to be able to search for a list of users that have `item 1` and `item 3` assigned to them, and return that users ID to get their info.

Example Table:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ USER ║ ITEM ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║  3   ║  1   ║
║  2 ║  5   ║  12  ║
║  3 ║  3   ║  3   ║
║  4 ║  1   ║  4   ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Would return `user 3` as having both `item 1` and `item 3`

I'm not even sure where to start. Any ideas?? I can try add more info if needed, just not sure what.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409869/mysql-nm-relationship-find-rows-with-several-specific-relations

Comment: @Rufinus thanks for that. The first answer I had on here worked but has now been removed so can't vote for it. That makes sense! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE item IN (1,3)
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(item) = 2
```

See [Get all entries from Table B which have a relation to multiple entries (given list) from Table A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650786/get-all-entries-from-table-b-which-have-a-relation-to-multiple-entries-given-li/26652551) for something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having` to do this.  The general SQL is:

```
select user
from table t
group by user
having sum(case when item = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when item = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match either `1` or `3`.  The `> 0` specifies that each value needs to exist.